# Connecting elements in list

Tags: luatex, lists, foreach, loops

How to connect these elements so i can get linked list, foreach needs to stay because its required in my project if someone could help??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.multipart,chains, arrows}



\tikzstyle{node} = [draw, rectangle split *->, text left]
\tikzstyle{strela} = [thick, ->, >=stealth]

\newcommand\x{10}
\newcommand\y{3}



\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
            draw, rectangle split horizontal}, start chain]
        
    \foreach \i in {\the\numexpr\y,...,\the\numexpr\x}{         
\node[list,on chain] (i) {\i};
         \draw[*->] let \p1 = (i.two), \p2 = (i.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (i);
     }  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is a more elegant solution, but this works in some sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,positioning}


\newcommand\x{10}
\newcommand\y{3}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ar/.style={*->,shorten <=-.28cm},list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, rectangle split horizontal,join=by ar}, start chain=going right]
        
     \foreach \i in {\the\numexpr\y,...,\the\numexpr\x}{
        \node[list,on chain] (i) {\i};

     }  
     

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]